# H1B first time filing W4, should I file as Resident Alien or Non Resident Alien?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, withholding, form-w-4

Please tell me whether I must file W4 as Resident Alien or Non Resident Alien?

- I entered the US on H1B in early June with family. I need to file W4 for withholding taxes.
- By the end of this year I will meet the substantial presence test i.e lived for more than 183 day in the current year.

Comment: So, how was it, I'm in a similar situation and don't know what to do. http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/determining-resident-status-for-an-h1b-filling-w-4-form/64070#64070

Answer (score 1):

> By the end of this year i will meet the substantial presence test i.e
>   Lived for more than 183 day in the current year.

That means that for tax purposes you'll be considered resident.

Comment: Agree. http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040nr/ch01.html#d0e296